# How can I set the brightness for each window opened?

Tags: display, brightness

I code on an IDE which has a dark theme. I require a high brightness while doing this task.

But when executing code, I use the browser, (since this is web development), and the whites of the browser coupled with high brightness cause strain.

Is there a way to control brightness with respect to the window which is active?

That is, if the IDE was open, the brightness would be max and if the browser was open then the brightness would be low.

Brightness here refers to the monitor backlight.

Answer (score 1):

Brightness is a monitor-related property, not a window's. That means brightenss changes for all that's displayed on a monitor at the same time.

I see 2 ways out of your predicaments:

1. Use dual monitors - have your IDE on one and the rest of the windows on the other. Set your IDE's monitor's brightness to full
2. Write a shell script (whichever OS you use supports it) that sets the brightness of the monitor every time the window's focus changes. If the window's title is equal to your IDE's set brightness to full, or otherwise lower it